# Python NameError: name 'current_player' is not defined

Tags: python

I've just got started with Python and decided to make a Tic-Tac-Toe project. However, I am not able to understand the following error:

**Error displayed:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/a/Desktop/Visual Studio Code/Tic-Tac-Toe Project/main.py", line 57, in <module>
play_game()

File "c:/Users/a/Desktop/Visual Studio Code/Tic-Tac-Toe Project/main.py", line 53, in play_game
handle_turn()

File "c:/Users/a/Desktop/Visual Studio Code/Tic-Tac-Toe Project/main.py", line 29, in handle_turn
player_turn_swap()

File "c:/Users/a/Desktop/Visual Studio Code/Tic-Tac-Toe Project/main.py", line 42, in player_turn_swap
if current_player == 'X':

NameError: name 'current_player' is not defined
```

**My code**

```
#VARIABLES
board = ["_" , "_", "_", 
     "_" , "_", "_",
     "_" , "_", "_"]

global current_player
position = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]


#FUNCTIONS
def display_board():
  print(board[0] + " | " + board[1] + " | " + board[2] + "     1 | 2 | 3")
  print(board[3] + " | " + board[4] + " | " + board[5] + "     4 | 5 | 6")
  print(board[6] + " | " + board[7] + " | " + board[8] + "     7 | 8 | 9")

def handle_turn():
  display_board()
  position = input("Choose an position from 1-9: ")

  if position in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]:
      position = int(position) - 1

      if board[position] == 'X' or board[position] == 'O':
          print("Position occupied. Go again!")

      elif board[position] == '_':                #if position is empty, replace it with "X" or "O"
          board[position] = 'X'
          current_player = 'X'
          player_turn_swap()

          position = input("Choose an position from 1-9: ")
          board[position] = current_player
          display_board()

          player_turn_swap()

  else: print("Invalid choice. Go again!")


def player_turn_swap():        #change turns
  global current_player
  if current_player == 'X':
      current_player = 'O'
  elif current_player == 'O':
      current_player = 'X'

  return current_player


def play_game():
  a = 0          #Play5Times
  while a < 6: 
      handle_turn()
      a += 1


play_game()      #call play_game
```

I've tried assigning

> global current_player = 'X'

in the first declaration as well (in #variables) but it doesn't allow me to do so...

Please provide a solution along with some suggestions (if any).
Thanks.

Comment: initialize current_player as string like global current_player instead current_player = ' '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of the file, you don't need to write `global current_player` - instead (at the same place at the top of the file) create a variable and assign some initial value to it:

```
current_player = 'X'  # Or some other initial value
```

Declaring a variable `global` is only needed inside a scope (it means "don't look for the variable here, but use the global scope"), not at the top of the file :) Also, consider using `nonlocal` instead of `global` - see [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/nonlocal-python) for more details.

Comment: Also, for general knowledge - `global <some_variable>` is a declaration about how a variable should be referred to, but it's not an expression you can combine with other expressions (so you can't do `global <some_variable> = <some_value>`.

Comment: I made the above change but it pops up with another error:File "c:/Users/a/Desktop/Visual Studio Code/Tic-Tac-Toe Project/main.py", line 32, in handle_turn
    board[position] = current_player
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: See the answer below by @mushif-ali-nawaz for a solution to the second error

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems in this code:

On 6th line, `global current_player` should be `current_player = None` or any other value.

And then in the following statement:

```
  elif board[position] == '_': #if position is empty, replace it with "X" or "O"
      # ... 
      position = input("Choose an position from 1-9: ")
      board[position] = current_player # <----- Problem Here!!
      display_board()
```

Here you are accessing the `str` index, it will give you an error. You should also convert this `position` variable from `str` to `int` like you're doing it above:

```
position = int(position) - 1  # this statement is missing
board[position] = current_player
```

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no need to declare a variable global.
2. on line 32 replace the position with int(position) as

   **board[int(position)-1] = current_player**